# how do I setup notification rules for email in my exchange inbox?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, email, htc-evo, exchange

At my company, I get WAY too much email to endure notification on ALL items. But maybe Boss and team emails are worth getting interupted for. (then again maybe not!)
I don't see a way to do this yet.

I'm on 2.2 with an HTC Evo (powered by the speedy Qualcomm Snapdragon!)

BG: I've been a stack overflow fan for years (and don't like PhBB that much), and Just got my android Phone. 
I'd like to help this site get better.

Comment: PS I'd really like to help upvote questions or even answers.. But I can't !! I don't recall that 5 rep was needed to upvote back when I started using stack overflow!

Comment: I was panicking.  didn't know I just had to wait 20 min after first question.

Answer (score 1):

Try these apps:

- [Mail Alert](http://market.android.com/details?id=com.willdev.mailalert) by DroidDevWork ([on AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/app/mail-alert/com.willdev.mailalert))
- [MailDroid](http://market.android.com/details?id=com.maildroid) by Flipdog ([on AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/app/maildroid/com.maildroid))

Disclaimer: I have never used any of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try eNotify or eNotifyLite...It enables you to customize email notificiatons and create your own alerts based on the subject, sender and other properties: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hermes.enotifylite

Comment: I notice that both of your posts so far promote this app. Please ensure you are mindful of our [FAQ#promotion].

Comment: According to Richard: `enotify only works for exchange 2007 and 2010 not for previous versions`